# weblogic integrated instance start from command line

Tags: weblogic11g

The test server instance in jdeveloper of WLS how do I start from command line without having to start jdeveloper for it.

I imported and deployed few projects to internal WLS and to keep them running so would prefer to start / stop using command line.  I have used all default settings for install.

Below you see my middleware dir where jdeveloper and domains are installed.  The domain has no shell files to start/stop the instance.

```
[root@NVMBD01VSR383 Middleware]# cd user_projects/applications/DefaultDomain/
[root@NVMBD01VSR383 DefaultDomain]# ls
[root@NVMBD01VSR383 DefaultDomain]# ls -al
total 8
drwxr-x--- 2 mhood mhood 4096 Dec 22 15:05 .
drwxr-x--- 3 mhood mhood 4096 Dec 22 15:05 ..
[root@NVMBD01VSR383 DefaultDomain]# pwd
/home/mhood/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/applications/DefaultDomain
[root@NVMBD01VSR383 DefaultDomain]# cd ..
[root@NVMBD01VSR383 applications]# ls
DefaultDomain
[root@NVMBD01VSR383 applications]# cd ..
[root@NVMBD01VSR383 user_projects]# cd ..
[root@NVMBD01VSR383 Middleware]# ls
domain-registry.xml  jdk160_24  modules        patch_jdev1111  registry.dat  user_projects  wlserver_10.3
jdeveloper           logs       oracle_common  patch_wls1035   registry.xml  utils
```

I though see some files as below:

```
/home/mhood/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/common/bin
[root@NVMBD01VSR383 bin]# ls
commEnv.sh         config.sh  setPatchEnv.sh           unpack.sh   wlscontrol.sh   wlst.sh
config_builder.sh  pack.sh    startManagedWebLogic.sh  upgrade.sh  wlsifconfig.sh
[root@NVMBD01VSR383 bin]# cd ..
[root@NVMBD01VSR383 common]# ls
bin  deployable-libraries  lib  nodemanager  quickstart  templates  wlst
[root@NVMBD01VSR383 common]# ls nodemanager/
nodemanager.domains
```

Regards,

Miten.

Comment: Your weblogic domain folder should have `<domain>/bin/startWebLogic.sh` to start the admin server without jdeveloper. You can start managed servers with `<domain>/bin/startManagedWebLogic.sh`

Comment: I added more info.  I do not see startWebLogic.sh in entire dir tree. I know its there if you install weblogic standalone but here its integrated as part of jdeveloper.

Comment: /home/mhood/.jdeveloper/system11.1.1.7.40.64.93/DefaultDomain [mhood@NVMBD01VSR383 DefaultDomain]$ ls
autodeploy  config       edit.lok              init-info  logs    pending   servers      startWebLogic.sh
bin         console-ext  fileRealm.properties  lib        oracle  security  shutdown.py  tmp    I see that its in above path and works fine.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
[mhood@NVMBD01VSR383 DefaultDomain]$ ls
autodeploy  config       edit.lok              init-info  logs    pending   servers      startWebLogic.sh
bin         console-ext  fileRealm.properties  lib        oracle  security  shutdown.py  tmp
[mhood@NVMBD01VSR383 DefaultDomain]$ pwd
/home/mhood/.jdeveloper/system11.1.1.7.40.64.93/DefaultDomain
[mhood@NVMBD01VSR383 DefaultDomain]$
```

Its in .jdeveloper directory.  Its hidden.